# If my own server is down, my aws container needs to go up. Is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a web app that is deployed on my server. But, I want to be able to know when the server is down. I know there are many tools on the internet that I can use to monitor. So, I want to know if is possible, if my server is down, another container located on AWS container be automatically set to go up. Or, vice versa.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes.
The most straightforward solution is to have a lambda checking /health of your own server every minute let's say. If you need to check more often, you'd have to either start a micro instance of ec2 or fargate or loop in lambda which is not ideal. Then if your server is down, you simply start a container using aws-sdk (boto3 in python for example, or aws-sdk in javascript). Now, the other way around could be also based on lambda, but the trick is, you need to expose some mechanism which starts your own server. But if you use for example fargate service, your task will be recreated based on your policies, so no need to start external server